# Redirección del registro de Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Queria saber si es posible tener dos redirecciones posibles en el registro de un usuario. Es decir, si están en cualquier página y le dan a registrarse va a `/mi-cuenta`. Pero por ejemplo mi app es una tienda online, cuando añaden productos al carrito no les hace falta estar logueados, pero al darle a confirmar pedido que pasariamos a el checkout si les hace falta estar registrados. La pregunta es, si estoy en la página `mi-carrito`, al darle al botón de confirmar pedido para pasar al checkout, me pide iniciar sesión o registrarme, es posible que conforme se registre se vaya a `confirmar-pedido` ?

Os expongo el caso de lo mismo de pasar de mi carrito a confirmar pedido, si me logueo por que ya tengo cuenta, si que me lleva a confirmar pedido.

En Laravel hay un archivo que esta en `app\Http\Controllers\RegisterController.php\` donde esta la función de que hacer cuando se registran.

```
protected $redirectTo = '/mi-cuenta';
```

¿Es posible hacer lo que digo?

**Archivo LoginController**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $this->guard()->logout();

        $request->session()->invalidate();

        return $this->loggedOut($request) ?: redirect('/login');
    }

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/mi-cuenta';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

Comment: Si, es posible. Pero se necesitan unos datos más para poder ayudarte. Tu LoginController por ejemplo, o dónde guardás los datos del carrito. Como para identificar si es un usuario que confirmó el pedido o un login normal. Se accede desde distintos lugares?

Comment: Hola y gracias por tu respuesta @JuanMartínPagella pues mañana cuando tenga un pc cerca publico el logincomtroller, los datos del carrito esta en una session, de echo esa sesión se carga tanto en el carrito como en el confirmar pedido

Comment: Ya he puesto el archivo LoginController @JuanMartínPagella

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tenés varias opciones de hacerlo:

**1. Verificar si tiene productos al momento de redirigir el usuario.**

[Authenticating - Path customization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#included-authenticating)

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
    //Verificar si tiene productos en el carrito
    if (session('<tu carrito>') === null) {
        return '/mi-cuenta';
    }
    return '/confirmar-pedido';
}
```

**2. Verificar al momento de devolver la vista de mi-cuenta.**

Suponiendo que tenés una ruta como esta:

```
Route::get('/mi-cuenta', 'PageController@index')->middleware('auth');
```

En el controlador podrías tener tu función como:

```
class PageController extends Controller
{

    function index()
    {
        //Verificar carrito
        if (session('<tu carrito>') === null) {
            return view('<vista a la cuenta>');
        }
        return view('<vista al carrito>');
    }
}
```

**3. Login personalizado**

[Authentication - Manually athenticating users](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#authenticating-users)

Sobreescribir la función `athenticate` que está dentro de `AuthenticatesUsers`. Esto se hace dentro del `LoginController`

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            //Verificar carrito
            if (session('<tu carrito>') === null) {
                return redirect()->intended('mi-cuenta');
            }
            return redirect()->intended('confirmar-pedido');
        }
    }
```

Tené en cuenta que usando cualquiera de las opciones, aún tenés más. Por ejemplo, enviar además de email y password, un link al carrito si se está logueando desde algún lado que no sea la web principal. No sé cómo estarás armando el proyecto y cuál sería la mejor alternativa.

Comment: Muchas gracias @JuanMartínPagella a funcionado perfecto, he utilizado la primera forma que me recomendabas y a la primera, GRACIAS! ;)